# Google Analytics , Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

Ques:- I want to know that how many users saw my android application page in google play and how many of them installed it?

Answer (score 0):

You get detailed statistics on the install performance of your app in the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish).

You can see installation metrics measured by unique users as well as by unique devices. View active installs, total installs, upgrades, daily installs and uninstalls, and metrics about ratings.

Also, you can zoom into the installation numbers by metric, including Android platform version, device, country, language, app version, and carrier. View the installation data for each dimension on timeline charts.

[image]

Reference: https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html#app-stats

Comment: Hi Aygul , Thanks for reply . Correct me if I am wrong . Google Play Developer Console gives me total installs per day by user or by device or by any metric which I set . But what if I want to know how many people saw my application page on a particular day . I just want to see the Conversion rate of users who saw my application page and how many of them installed it,